# How to set reference of already opened database vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I'm trying to get recordset for already opened database from excel vba. Get reference of opened db in **daoDB** variable. My excel vba code

```
Public Sub getdatafromaccess1()
Dim daoDB As DAO.Database
Dim daoQueryDef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim daoRcd As DAO.Recordset

'Here i want to reference to already opened database instead of opening


Set daoDB= OpenDatabase("C:\temp\sample.accdb")
Set daoQueryDef = daoDB.QueryDefs("Headings")
Set daoRcd = daoQueryDef.OpenRecordset
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("w1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset daoRcd

End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify, already opened via code earlier in the excel vba? Or opened via linked db to the excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Already opened via code earlier in the excel vba

Comment: if it was opened previously (like this line exists elsewhere `Set daoDB= OpenDatabase("C:\temp\sample.accdb")`) then just use the `daoDB` reference again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maintain cleaner and accessible code it would be a wise idea to move your connection status to a global variable so that way you can utilize the object across all functions and subs.

**Update** - This will maintain the connection within the workbook while it is open.

```
Global daoDB As DAO.Database

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set daoDB = OpenDatabase("C:\temp\sample.accdb") 'Your DB connection function
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    daoDB.Close
End Sub
```